# No energy consumed in planetary motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

Most of the orbits of planet are elliptical. How is it then that no energy is consumed?

Comment: Please consider adding your reasoning to your question; why do you suspect energy is not conserved for elliptical orbits but is conserved for circular orbits?

Answer (score 2):

The ellipse is a part of the [solutions of the equations for orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit) in a gravitational two body problem.

[image: orbits]

> A diagram of the various forms of the Kepler Orbit and their eccentricities. Blue is a hyperbolic trajectory (e > 1). Green is a parabolic trajectory (e = 1). Red is an elliptical orbit (0 < e < 1). Grey is a circular orbit (e = 0).

Look here for [energy budgets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_mechanics#Energy) for different orbits i.e. the play between potential and kinetic energy.

Answer (score 1):

For instance, in moon-earth system:$$\textbf{F}=F(\textbf{r})\textbf{e}_r$$where F($\textbf{r}$) means magnitude of $\textbf{F}$, and $\textbf{e}_r=\frac{\textbf{r}}{r}$ is unit vector pointing from the center of moon to the center of earth.

This kind of force has some important properties.

1.angular-momentum $\textbf{J}$ of moon is conserved(if we ignore the motion of earth).

because we can prove$$\frac{d\textbf{J}}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}(\textbf{r}\times m\textbf{v})=\textbf{r}\times\textbf{F}=\textbf{r}\times\frac{\textbf{r}}{r}F=0$$2.moon is doing plane motion,thus we can use a relative coordinate to describe it, which called plane polar coordinate.

3.The gravitational potential $V(r)$ of moon is spherical symmetric.

Thus, we have the Lagrangian:$$L(r,r')=T-V=\frac{1}{2}m(r'^2+r^2\theta'^2)-V(r)$$

as you can see, the Lagrangian doesn't depend on time explicitly,

so, we can say that the total energy of moon is conserved.

which is:$$E=T+V=\frac{1}{2}m(r'^2+r^2\theta'^2)+V(r)$$